# custom domain SSL in app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, https, dns, google-apps

My application has the following urls:

- client-1.myapp.appspot.com
- client-2.myapp.appspot.com

I want to use a custom subdomains:

- client-1.myapp.com
- client-2.myapp.com

To do this:

- I added a txt record to myapp.com and verified my domain.
- Then I added a cname record for *.myapp.com to ghs.googlehosted.com.

This works great, when client-3 comes along I dont even need to set anything up (except in my code). However, a client will eventually want to use their own domain instead of mine.

For Example:

- sub.client-1-website.com
- client-2-website.org

If my app was in a normal lamp stack they could just do a cname record for sub.client-1-website.com to client-1.myapp.com (or client-2-website.org to client-2.myapp.com).
My app would then have a vhost that points that to the correct location.

In app engine if that's all they did it would lead to a 404 page.
I must go into my add dashboard, verify the domain as mine, add it as one of my custom domains, then they can cname sub.client-1-website.com to client-1.myapp.com (or ghs.googlehosted.com.).

This means my clients must add and keep a google-verification txt record in their dns.

Is it possible to have app engine route the request based on the domain they were cnamed to?
sub.client-1-website.com -cname-> client-1.myapp.com -cname-> client-1.myapp.appspot.com
So app engine would route based on client-1.myapp.appspot.com
I have a feeling the answer is no.
This would be due to a limitation of how cnames work (not some a limitation in app engine).
Is that correct?

At the end of the day this isn't a deal breaker. Its just one extra step for me and my client. However, things get super hairy when we add SSL into the mix.

I know how to set up SSL for *.myapp.com though Google Apps. It is annoying that I have to go through Google Apps, but not a deal breaking because only I need to do that.

However, if my client wants to use their own domain (sub.client-1-website.com and client-2-website.org) they too would need to go though Google Apps to have SSL work wouldn't they?

Is there another way for my clients to be able to add SSL?

Answer (score 0):

As of September 2015, AppEngine SSL is no longer based on Google Apps. Through the appengine console, you can add `client-1-website.com` as a custom domain, verify ownership of it, and then add an SSL certificate for that domain.

I think you'll find the original domain name in the request headers but I haven't checked.